# How to show throbber when loading file content to Iframe

Tags: jquery, angularjs, httprequest

Download multiple Files with IFrame.In case of higher size Files takes too much time to download the file. I want to show a loading image while downloading the file. iframe.onload  function works only before giving value to iframe.src